# Select2 not working after doing a dom that uses select2

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-select2

I using multiple select2 by using a different class and id, but if using DOM one of select2 suddenly not working,,

select2 can't do data transaction via ajax,,

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pelanggan").select2({
    minimumInputLength : 3,
    ajax : {
      url                : "<?= $base_url; ?>/api/api.php",
      type               : "POST",
      dataType           : "JSON",
      data: function (params) {
          return {
              proses    : "data_pelanggan",
              pelanggan : params.term
          };
      },
      processResults : function (response) {
          return {
              results : response
          };
      },
      cache : true
    }
  });
});

function add_transaksi() {
  var index = $("#total_detail").val();
  $("#total_detail").val(parseInt($("#total_detail").val())+1);

  var detail_transaksi = document.getElementById("detail_transaksi");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.setAttribute("id", "tr_"+index);

  // Kolom 1 Checkbox
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.setAttribute("align","center");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' name='detail_"+index+"' onchange='hapus_produk("+index+")' checked>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 2 Select
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<select name='produk_"+index+"' id='produk_"+index+"' class='form-control select2' onchange='cek_produk(this,"+index+")' style='width:100%;' x-moz-errormessage='Silakan pilih produk.' required><?php $HP = $Mod_Tampil->tampil_all($db,'SELECT ID_PRODUK,NAMA_PRODUK FROM PRODUK WHERE md5(ID_TOKO)="'.$_SESSION['TOKO'].'" ORDER BY NAMA_PRODUK ASC'); ?><option type hidden selected value=''>- <?= bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pilih'); ?> -</option><?php if (!empty($HP[0])) { foreach ($HP[1] as $DP) { ?><option value='<?= $DP[0]; ?>'><?= $DP[1]; ?></option><?php } } ?></select>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 3 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='beli_"+index+"' id='beli_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly required> <input type='text' name='jual_"+index+"' id='jual_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly required>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 4 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='number' name='jumlah_"+index+"' id='jumlah_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' oninput='cek_persediaan(this,"+index+")' required>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 5 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='number' name='diskon_"+index+"' value='<?= $diskon; ?>' id='diskon_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' oninput='perhitungan_sub("+index+")'>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 6 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='sub_"+index+"' id='sub_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  detail_transaksi.appendChild(tr);

  $('.select2').select2();
}
```

```html
<select name="pelanggan" class="form-control" id="pelanggan" style="width:100%;" x-moz-errormessage="Silakan pilih pelanggan.">
              <option type hidden selected value="">- <?= bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pilih')." ".bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pelanggan'); ?> -</option>
            </select>
```

how do I make select2 still work even though I use a dom that has select2 too ?

Please help for this problem, and thank you for support me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the select2 at the end of your function to create elements with a callback function after the last element loads, like the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pelanggan").select2({
    minimumInputLength : 3,
    ajax : {
      url                : "<?= $base_url; ?>/api/api.php",
      type               : "POST",
      dataType           : "JSON",
      data: function (params) {
          return {
              proses    : "data_pelanggan",
              pelanggan : params.term
          };
      },
      processResults : function (response) {
          return {
              results : response
          };
      },
      cache : true
    }
  });
});

function add_transaksi() {
  var index = $("#total_detail").val();
  $("#total_detail").val(parseInt($("#total_detail").val())+1);

  var detail_transaksi = document.getElementById("detail_transaksi");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.setAttribute("id", "tr_"+index);

  // Kolom 1 Checkbox
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.setAttribute("align","center");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' name='detail_"+index+"' onchange='hapus_produk("+index+")' checked>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 2 Select
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<select name='produk_"+index+"' id='produk_"+index+"' class='form-control select2' onchange='cek_produk(this,"+index+")' style='width:100%;' x-moz-errormessage='Silakan pilih produk.' required><?php $HP = $Mod_Tampil->tampil_all($db,'SELECT ID_PRODUK,NAMA_PRODUK FROM PRODUK WHERE md5(ID_TOKO)="'.$_SESSION['TOKO'].'" ORDER BY NAMA_PRODUK ASC'); ?><option type hidden selected value=''>- <?= bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pilih'); ?> -</option><?php if (!empty($HP[0])) { foreach ($HP[1] as $DP) { ?><option value='<?= $DP[0]; ?>'><?= $DP[1]; ?></option><?php } } ?></select>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 3 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='beli_"+index+"' id='beli_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly required> <input type='text' name='jual_"+index+"' id='jual_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly required>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 4 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='number' name='jumlah_"+index+"' id='jumlah_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' oninput='cek_persediaan(this,"+index+")' required>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 5 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='number' name='diskon_"+index+"' value='<?= $diskon; ?>' id='diskon_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' oninput='perhitungan_sub("+index+")'>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Kolom 6 Input
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='sub_"+index+"' id='sub_"+index+"' class='form-control' style='text-align:right;' readonly>";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  // Here is the callback
  tr.onload = function(){
      $('select[name*="produk_"]').select2();
  }

  detail_transaksi.appendChild(tr);

}
```

```html
<select name="pelanggan" class="form-control" id="pelanggan" style="width:100%;" x-moz-errormessage="Silakan pilih pelanggan.">
              <option type hidden selected value="">- <?= bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pilih')." ".bahasa($_SESSION['BAHASA'],'Pelanggan'); ?> -</option>
            </select>
```

Also if you append with jquery the elements you can use `ready` method as your callback like this:

```
$("#container").append(newSelect2).ready(function(){
       $('select[name*="produk_"]').select2();
    })
})
```

Comment: Hii @Jose Lora , I used tr.onload = function(){ $('.select2').select2(); } and it worked for function $("#pelanggan").select2({}) , but my function add_transaksi() {} suddenly not working,,

Comment: Hii @Jose Lora after I used : 

$("#produk_"+index).select2();
  
  tr.onload = function(){
    $('.select2').select2();
  }

all my function is working : )

Thank you Jose Lora